# ( DONE ) Reopening a question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-request

This question: [Asking an update from a friend who agreed to help me but who didn't respond me last time](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/21175/21067) was closed and then edited.

The user who asks the question is new and really active (they clearly want to see their question reopened). The question already did go through the review queue but it was between edit and now the question is fine (IMO) but isn't in the review queue anymore.

So, could we reopen this (quickly) or explain to me (and the OP) why this is still not on-topic?

Comment: This was reopened on March 8th.

Comment: Looking at e.g. workplace meta questions tagged reopen-request, it seems fine to just indicate this in the title instead of putting the question on-hold: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request. One side-effect of closing is that the question will be removed as abandoned-closed after a while, if the community wants this, it's fine with me to close, otherwise perhaps better to leave them open. But that's perhaps a different discussion ;)

Comment: @scohe001 A valid answer is that the issue has been resolved. Compare to Feature Requests and Bug Reports – when the feature is implemented or the bug is fixed the question doesn't get closed. An answer is usually posted stating what was done, and the question gets a status-completed tag.